# How to use v-icon in vuetify text-area label instead of text?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to use v-icon in vuetify text-area label instead of text? if so what is the best way to do it.

```
<v-textarea
  outlined
  label="DEMO"
  value="Hello World"
/>
```

this is what i tried

```
<v-textarea
  outlined
  label=<v-icon>fas fa-lock</v-icon>
  value="Hello World"
/>
```

Here is what it looks without icon

[image]

Here is what i want

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use slot

```
<v-textarea outlined value="Hello World"/>
  <template slot="label">
    <v-icon>you icon</v-icon>
  </template>           
</v-textarea>
```

Comment: Your code pen link just links to an empty editor. Fix that and I’ll remove the downvote.

Comment: Sorry guys,i removed it

Comment: @MerouaneBoucenna I updated my question with screenshot on what i am looking for,

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the input.